# How do I see what viewController a class is attached to?

Tags: xcode, class, uiviewcontroller

It's easy to tell what `class` a `viewController` uses, but what about the other way around: if you have a `class` and wants to see what `viewController` it's attached to. Is there a way to do that? I'm now in a peculiar position where I have made changes in a `class` but don't know how to test the changes because I don't know which `viewController` to enter in the simulator to see the result.

Comment: The name of the class should make it obvious. If it doesn't then you should work on improving your naming conventions.

Comment: But I didn't name anything. I just started working on a project where someone else named all the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the screenshot then you will get the name of your viewcontroller class.

1. select Main Storyboard
2. select your ViewController
3. select identity inspector
4. you will see the class name

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is the other way around. I already know the class, but I don't know the viewController. I want to find the viewController from the class, not the other way around.